# Failed GIMP installation due to

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to  install GIMP for Ubuntu 12.10 from Ubuntu SW center but any times I try I get  the replay that I' cannot reach the repository and I've to check my Internet connection. That is properly working with Firefox and Thunderbird. In addition appears the info that not safe program cannot be installed because of lack of authentication. May anybody give a some explanation?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10 is end of life and so are their repositories. Please upgrade to 14.04 or 14.10 by re-installing. This will fix all your installation problems. End of life versions of Ubuntu are off topic on AU :)

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

In the open file, delete the content and paste this:

```
## Uncomment the following two lines to fetch updated software from the network
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal main restricted

## Uncomment the following two lines to fetch major bug fix updates produced
## after the final release of the distribution.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-updates main restricted

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'universe'
## repository.
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal universe

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security main restricted

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-security universe

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal multiverse
deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu quantal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Ctrl + O, save file. Ctrl + X, close nano.

Continue run in a terminal:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install gimp
apt-get clean
```

Comment: No improvement to suggest . It helps me very much, not only for GIMP. By this some minor problems on running Ubuntu have been fixed